# Galois group of zeta function of hyperelliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, zeta-functions, galois-groups

Let $f \in \mathbb F_q[T]$ be monic, squarefree.

Can we say anything on the Galois group of $Z_f$, the zeta function of the hyperelliptic curve $y^2=f$, directly in terms of $f$ (coefficients or Galois group for example) ? I am especially interested in conditions implying maximality (or not !) of the Galois group of $Z_f$.